# Exchange 2013 Blocking redirect of OOF messages to external

Tags: redirection, exchange-2013, out-of-office

on the Exchange 2013-cluster I have a problem with redirect of OOF messages. Users who redirect all incoming emails to an external address per inboxrule, get all email in the targetmailbox except OOF notifications. There is an abstract from Message Tracking Log:

```
SourceContext           : BlockInternalOofToExternalUser
Source                  : ROUTING
EventId                 : DROP
Recipients              : {external Redirectaddress}
RecipientStatus         : {[{LRT=};{LED=250 2.1.5 RESOLVER.OOF.IntToExt; handled internal OOF addressed to external recipient};{FQDN=};{IP=}]}

Configuration Renote-Domain “*”:
Get-RemoteDomain|fl
DomainName                           : *
IsInternal                           : False
TargetDeliveryDomain                 : False
ByteEncoderTypeFor7BitCharsets       : Undefined
CharacterSet                         : iso-8859-1
NonMimeCharacterSet                  :
AllowedOOFType                       : External
AutoReplyEnabled                     : True
AutoForwardEnabled                   : True
DeliveryReportEnabled                : True
NDREnabled                           : True
MeetingForwardNotificationEnabled    : True
ContentType                          : MimeHtmlText
DisplaySenderName                    : True
PreferredInternetCodePageForShiftJis : Undefined
RequiredCharsetCoverage              :
TNEFEnabled                          :
LineWrapSize                         : Unlimited
TrustedMailOutboundEnabled           : False
TrustedMailInboundEnabled            : False
UseSimpleDisplayName                 : False
NDRDiagnosticInfoEnabled             : True
```

How can the OOF messages are redirected to external users?

Thank you for your support, 
Regina

Answer (score 0):

This is a cosmetic issue that will only be visible in a message trace.
It applies to an internal OOF message and the message trace will show that there was an SMTP drop event for an External OOF message.
The internal OOF message is delivered successfully and an external is dropped while the sender was an internal sender there should be no external OOF message generated in the first place.
So this can be ignored.
You may see the same (reversed) for an External OOF message where an internal drop event is visible in a message trace.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify [Sabir’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/987556/150988#1181114):

This is applied in the Exchange management shell / Exchange online shell session.

Firstly run:

```
Get-RemoteDomain
```

On the domain you want to set the Allow Out of office type to run:

```
Set-RemoteDomain " contoso.local" -TNEFEnabled $true -AllowedOOFType "ExternalLegacy"
```

Comment: Great so Jeroen Rewords my answer and posts as his when my response got deleted? Bit unethical if you ask me. But hey at least someone learnt something.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the OOF setting as below which willhandle both new and old style of OOF messages

AllowedOOFType                       : ExternalLegacy

Comment: This answer would be improved by including information on what exactly that setting controls, and how to set it.